# Nested Az Cli commands not working in WSL

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, azure-cli, wsl-2

In general, I am trying to store the output of one Az CLI command in a variable and reference that variable in another Az CLI command. I see that it works in Azure Cloud Shell (Bash), but it does not work in WSL2 Ubuntu **22.04.3** LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64).

For instance, I get the principalId of a user-assigned managed identity and check if it has any role granted on some resource.

```
pid=$(az identity show -g rgName -n miName --query "principalId" -o tsv)
#Output: 1fcb8323-3b13-4de7-b53d-a5abc0c4556b

az role assignment list --assignee $pid --scope /subscriptions/{subid}/resourceGroups/{rgName}
```

The Principal Id is printed as expected. But the role assignment statement throws this error:
`'. If the assignee is an appId, make sure the corresponding service principal is created with 'az ad sp create --id 1fcb8323-3b13-4de7-b53d-a5abc0c4556b`

[image]
[image]

But the same two commands work in Azure Cloud shell (Bash).

Is there some nuance to WSL that I am missing? Can you please help me understand how I can make this work in WSL?

Comment: Try this command with quotes: az role assignment list --assignee "$pid" --scope /subscriptions/{subid}/resourceGroups/{rgName}/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/{clusterName}

Comment: @VenkatV I have tried that as well. It gives the same error.

Comment: Try this cmd also: echo "Assignee ID: $pid"
az role assignment list --assignee "$pid" --scope /subscriptions/{actual-subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{actual-rg-name}/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/{clusterName}

Comment: @VenkatV I added an image too of the script. It gives the same error.

Comment: As per [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/role/assignment?view=azure-cli-latest#az-role-assignment-list) --assignee: Represent a user, group, or service principal. supported format: object id, user sign-in name, or service principal name, it won't accepting Managed Identity Object ID.

Comment: When I try with the user/SP object ID, it's working, but when I use the Identity object ID, it's not working. You can check the [result here](https://i.imgur.com/9klUtWP.png). There is no issue with the command.

Comment: @VenkatV I added some pictures that add more clarity. Please have a look. The commands work with PrincipalId of the User assigned managed identity. If I use it separately, commands work. The only thing that does not work is when the principalId is brought from another Az CLI command and stored in a variable. This is what i am trying to troubleshoot in WSL (It works in Azure Cloud Shell Bash though).

Comment: For me its working, which is getting from CLI,  [here is my result](https://i.imgur.com/SwRPwgw.png), Logout and login the Az cli and check the same.

Comment: @VenkatV Thank you for helping out. I think I understand the issue, coz I was able to successfully run the commands in WSL Ubuntu 20.04. But the same fails in Ubuntu 22.04. is your system Ubuntu 20.04? I might have to raise an issue with WSL.

Comment: Yes, mine is Ubuntu 20.04.